# Callback from c# to java using UnmanagedExports

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface

What I require is that java to be able to pass in a function to c#, which c# can call back after execution. How do I do it?

Below are the two sample code snippets from Java and c# classes. This works for simply passing a string from java to c#.

Sample c# code

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Hello
{    
    public class Hello
    {
        public delegate void VoidStringDelegate(string str);

        [DllExport]
        public static unsafe string sayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello {0} from c#", name);
        }

        [DllExport]
        public static unsafe void processAndCallback(VoidStringDelegate callback)
        {
            callback("Started");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            callback("Done");
        }       

    }
}
```

Sample Java code

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Hello {

    public static class CallbackWrap 
    {   
        public void Callback(String msg) 
        {
            System.out.println("Call back: " + msg);
        }   
    };

    public interface IHello extends Library
    {
       public String sayHello(String tStr);
       public String processAndCallback(Method callback);      
    };  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");        
        IHello iHello = (IHello)Native.loadLibrary("Hello", IHello.class);//call JNA
        System.out.println("Returned: " + iHello.sayHello("Java"));

        Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[1];
        parameterTypes[0] = String.class;
        Method method1 = CallbackWrap.class.getMethod("CallbackWrap::Callback", parameterTypes);

        iHello.processAndCallback(method1);       
    }



}
```